# Writing to a TextBox from another thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I cannot figure out how to make a C# Windows Form application write to a textbox from a thread.  For example in the Program.cs we have the standard main() that draws the form:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Then we have in the Form1.cs:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    new Thread(SampleFunction).Start();
}

public static void SampleFunction()
{
    while(true)
        WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.ActiveForm.Text += "hi. ";
}
```

Am I going about this completely wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here is the working code sample provided from bendewey:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Thread(SampleFunction).Start();
    }

    public void AppendTextBox(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] {value});
            return;
        }
        textBox1.Text += value;
    }

    void SampleFunction()
    {
        // Gets executed on a seperate thread and 
        // doesn't block the UI while sleeping
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            AppendTextBox("hi.  ");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

On your MainForm make a function to set the textbox the checks the InvokeRequired

```
public void AppendTextBox(string value)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] {value});
        return;
    }
    ActiveForm.Text += value;
}
```

although in your static method you can't just call.

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.AppendTextBox("hi. ");
```

you have to have a static reference to the Form1 somewhere,  but this isn't really recommended or necessary, can you just make your SampleFunction not static if so then you can just call

```
AppendTextBox("hi. ");
```

It will append on a differnt thread and get marshalled to the UI using the Invoke call if required.

***Full Sample***

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Thread(SampleFunction).Start();
    }

    public void AppendTextBox(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] {value});
            return;
        }
        textBox1.Text += value;
    }

    void SampleFunction()
    {
        // Gets executed on a seperate thread and 
        // doesn't block the UI while sleeping
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            AppendTextBox("hi.  ");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it's not quite working for me.  I appreciate the answer mate.

Comment: More specifically, it compiles, but the TextBox isn't continuously being written to.

Comment: In your code you took out the while(true) put that back into your sample function and you should be rocking.  Thats gonna write a lot though.  You might want to put a Thread.Sleep(1000) for 1 sec if your trying to test responsiveness

Comment: Bendewey, you rock mate!  I probably spent 2 hours banging my head against my monitor.

Answer (score 20):

I would use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` as often as possible, unless you are really required to wait until your control has been updated (which in your example is not the case). `BeginInvoke` posts the delegate on the WinForms message queue and lets the calling code proceed immediately (in your case the for-loop in the `SampleFunction`). `Invoke` not only posts the delegate, but also waits until it has been completed.

So in the method `AppendTextBox` from your example you would replace `Invoke` with `BeginInvoke` like that:

```
public void AppendTextBox(string value)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] {value});
        return;
    }
    textBox1.Text += value;
}
```

Well and if you want to get even more fancy, there is also the `SynchronizationContext` class, which lets you basically do the same as `Control.Invoke/Control.BeginInvoke`, but with the advantage of not needing a WinForms control reference to be known. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/SyncContextTutorial.aspx) is a small tutorial on `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the difference between `BeginInvoke` and `Invoke`. This alone has solved my problem (and probably helped me out a lot in the future since `BeginInvoke` doesn't cause the waiting)

Comment: I have been trying the accepted answer with no result, my app always hanged. Thanks to this good explanation I can finally get some sleep again

Answer (score 16):

or you can do like

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Thread( SampleFunction ).Start();
    }

    void SampleFunction()
    {
        // Gets executed on a seperate thread and 
        // doesn't block the UI while sleeping
        for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        {
            this.Invoke( ( MethodInvoker )delegate()
            {
                textBox1.Text += "hi";
            } );
            Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and short. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Quite simply, without worrying about delegates and actions:

```
if(textBox1.InvokeRequired == true)
    textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox1.Text = "Invoke was needed";});

else
    textBox1.Text = "Invoke was NOT needed";
```

InvokeRequired checks whether the code is running on the UI thread or on a different thread. Only the UI thread is allowed to perform UI operations like changing the content of a control. When its not running on the UI thread, then the Invoke passes the operation temporarily to the UI thread.

This may slow down the performance and reduce the benefits of multy threading. In this case a queue with an event can be used. The backround thread puts the change on the queue and continues. The UI changes are performed in the event asynchrounisly.

Answer (score 5):

You need to perform the action from the thread that owns the control.

That's how I'm doing that without adding too much code noise:

```
control.Invoke(() => textBox1.Text += "hi");
```

Where Invoke overload is a simple extension from [Lokad Shared Libraries](http://abdullin.com/shared-libraries/):

```
/// <summary>
/// Invokes the specified <paramref name="action"/> on the thread that owns     
/// the <paramref name="control"/>.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="TControl">type of the control to work with</typeparam>
/// <param name="control">The control to execute action against.</param>
/// <param name="action">The action to on the thread of the control.</param>
public static void Invoke<TControl>(this TControl control, Action action) 
  where TControl : Control
{
  if (!control.InvokeRequired)
  {
    action();
  }
  else
  {
    control.Invoke(action);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Control.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) method. The point is to never update UI controls from another thread. BeginInvoke will dispatch the call to the UI thread of the control (in your case, the Form).

To grab the form, remove the static modifier from the sample function and use this.BeginInvoke() as shown in the examples from MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

What's even easier is to just use the BackgroundWorker control...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the what I have done to avoid `CrossThreadException` and writing to the textbox from another thread.

Here is my `Button.Click` function- I want to generate a random number of threads and then get their `IDs` by calling the `getID()` method and the TextBox value while being in that worker thread.

```
private void btnAppend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Random n = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < n.Next(1,5); i++)
    {
        label2.Text = "UI Id" + ((Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId).ToString());
        Thread t = new Thread(getId);
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

Here is `getId` (workerThread) code:

```
public void getId()
{
    int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    //Note that, I have collected threadId just before calling this.Invoke
    //method else it would be same as of UI thread inside the below code block 
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
    {
        inpTxt.Text += "My id is" +"--"+id+Environment.NewLine; 
    });
}
```