# How to access Form.cs methods in other class when there is multithreading c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Downloader: should I use Threads, BackgroundWorker or ThreadPool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913487/c-sharp-downloader-should-i-use-threads-backgroundworker-or-threadpool)
>   [C# , how reach something in current thread that created in other thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257238/c-sharp-how-reach-something-in-current-thread-that-created-in-other-thread)

So I have following code

Downloader.cs

```
class Downloader
{  
    private WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    public void saveImages(string picUrl, string path)
    {
                this.wc.DownloadFile(picUrl, path + p);
                Form1.Instance.log = picUrl + " is downloaded to folder " + path + ".";
    }
}
```

Form1.cs / Windows Form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static Form1 instance;
    public static Form1 Instance { get { return instance; } }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        instance = this;
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        instance = null;
    }
    public string log
    {
        set { logbox.AppendText(value); } // Logbox is Rich Text Box
    }
    private void ThreadJob()
    {
        Downloader r = new Downloader();
        r.saveImages("http://c.org/car.jpg","c:/temp/");
    }
    private void download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadStart job = new ThreadStart(ThreadJob);
        Thread thread = new Thread(job);
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

I need to get `Form1.Instance.log = picUrl + " is downloaded to folder " + path + ".";` working without `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` set to `false` because I've heard it's bad way to do things.

PS:: Some of the code is missing but I think the relevant information is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having `saveImages` be a `void` method and modifying the form, `saveImages` should return the string value that it computes and allow the form to modify itself:

```
public string saveImages(string picUrl, string path)
{
            this.wc.DownloadFile(picUrl, path + p);
            return picUrl + " is downloaded to folder " + path + ".";
}
```

Now what you're really looking for is a way of performing a long running task in a background thread and updating the UI with the result.  The `BackgroundWorker` class is specifically designed for that purpose, and is much easier to use in a winform application than directly dealing with threads.

You just need to create a `BackgroundWorker`, set the work that it needs to do in the `DoWork` event, and then update the UI in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

In this case, the `DoWork` just needs to call `saveImages` and then set the `Result` to the return value and then the completed event can add the `Result` to the rich text box.  The `BackgroundWorker` will ensure that the completed event will be run by the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

See documentation on BackgroundWorker or Control.Invoke.  Remember google is your friend.