# C# textchanged issue not updating

Tags: c#

Every 2.5 seconds this string is sent to a textbox,which contains sensor values etc`ADR=0x0100000000,FW=0x010B,BV=26,UL=40,SRC=3,SEss=10,TAMB=73,SQ=32886,STAT=0x03,RFrssi=227`

The string updates, the if else statements are doing there job but the textboxes containing the values are just staying the same. (txtUllage,txtSRC etc) They update the first time but dont update from their on. Is their something wrong with my loop

```
private void txtConsole_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((txtConsole.Text.Contains("STAT")) && (txtConsole.Text.Length > 85))
        {
            string Stat = "";
            int Ullage_12cm = 0;
            int Sonic_Result_Code_12cm = 0;
            int BV_12cm = 0;
            int tamb_12cm = 0;
            int PassCounter = 0;
            int SEss_12cm = 0;

                string[] splitstring = txtConsole.Text.Split(',');

                BV_12cm = Convert.ToInt32(splitstring[2].Replace("BV=", ""));
                txtBatteryVoltage.Text = BV_12cm.ToString();

                Ullage_12cm = Convert.ToInt32(splitstring[3].Replace("UL=", ""));
                txtUllage.Text = Ullage_12cm.ToString();

                Sonic_Result_Code_12cm = Convert.ToInt32(splitstring[4].Replace("SRC=", ""));
                txtSRC.Text = Sonic_Result_Code_12cm.ToString();

                SEss_12cm = Convert.ToInt32(splitstring[5].Replace("SEss=", ""));
                txtSESS.Text = SEss_12cm.ToString();

                tamb_12cm = Convert.ToInt32(splitstring[6].Replace("TAMB=", ""));
                txtTAMB.Text = tamb_12cm.ToString();

                if ((BV_12cm < spnMinBatt.Value) || (Ullage_12cm < SpnSonicLowval.Value - 2) || (Ullage_12cm > SpnSonicLowval.Value + 2) ||
                    Sonic_Result_Code_12cm < spnSRCLow.Value || (SEss_12cm < spnSEssLow.Value) || ((tamb_12cm < spnTambLow.Value) || (tamb_12cm > spnTambHigh.Value)))
                {
                    txtResultsReading.AppendText("BATT=" + txtBatteryVoltage.Text + "   Ullage=" + txtUllage.Text + "   SRC=" + txtSRC.Text + "   SESS=" + txtSESS.Text + "   TAMB=" + txtTAMB.Text + "   (FAIL)\r\n");
                    txtUllage.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    // PassCounter = 0;//reset pass count
                }

                else
                {
                    txtResultsReading.AppendText("BATT=" + txtBatteryVoltage.Text + "   Ullage=" + txtUllage.Text + "   SRC=" + txtSRC.Text + "   SESS=" + txtSESS.Text + "   TAMB=" + txtTAMB.Text + "   (PASS)\r\n");
                    txtUllage.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;

                    /*if (++PassCounter >= 6)//increment pass count
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(SpnSonicLowval.Value.ToString() + " cm test passed, now proceed to next test");
                    }*/
                }
            }
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing to a TextBox from another thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519233/writing-to-a-textbox-from-another-thread)

Comment: @Kami No The actual textbox itself is not updating. it only reads it once and doesnt check again it seems

Comment: has it something to do with application.doevents()

Answer (score 0):

You are using `AppendText` which appends the given text.  It is likely this scrolls off-screen is not visible.  Use the `.Text` property instead.

```
txtResultsReading.Text = "BATT=" + txtBatteryVoltage.Text + "   Ullage=" + txtUllage.Text + "   SRC=" + txtSRC.Text + "   SESS=" + txtSESS.Text + "   TAMB=" + txtTAMB.Text + "   (FAIL)\r\n";
```

MSDN:
[TextBox.Append()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx)
[TextBox.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6w057xy(v=vs.110).aspx)