# C# task can't access control in main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task

Using Winforms, C#, FW 4.5.
I have a simple form with a textbox and a gridView.
When I start a new task, it's able to access the cells of the grid and change the text. When I try to change the textbox text i get this error "cross thread operation not valid..."

Both the textbox and the gridView are on the same form. Why the behavior is different?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include the code *as text*, ideally as a [mcve], rather than showing a screenshot. Fundamentally, you simply shouldn't be accessing a UI control on a different thread. The fact that it happens to work for the textbox is surprising but you should still not do it...

Comment: Read on this here. Textboxes and plenty of other controls can not be written to from outside their main thread. [This question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519233/writing-to-a-textbox-from-another-thread) should give you some inspiration on how to solve your problem.

Comment: Avoid manipulating controls from non-UI thread. In fact, you can't even do that with some controls. Make some form of intermediate list or  object to which you can store data ( you'll still need to lock that object ) and update form when you're done. 
Also consider using BackgroundWorker if the task is time demanding and you want to keep the form updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to access your UI from a different thread than the one which started the UI. It is possible to avoid the exception by setting the static property `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `false`, but that is a very dangerous way.

You should rather use [`Control.BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) to defer execution back to the UI thread.

So you could replace your line `txtSql.Text = sQuery` to something like that:

```
void RunChecks()
{
    ...
    SetQueryText(sQuery); // instead of txtSql.Text = sQuery;
    ...
}

delegate void SetTextDelegate(string text);
void SetQueryText(string query)
{
    if (txtSql.InvokeRequired)
    {
        txtSql.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDelegate(SetQueryText), query);
        return;
    }
    txtSql.Text = query;
}
```

So `SetQueryText` checks if it is necessary to call `Invoke` (or `BeginInvoke`) because it was called from another thread. If this is the case, it calls `BeginInvoke` to defer execution to the UI thread and returns.

Unfortunatly this still uses the delegate syntax instead of lambdas, but maybe there's a better syntax that I just don't know.

You need to do this for all controls you are accessing from different threads.