# How to open Windows Form from with mdiParent in timer method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

I have a `MainForm` and method which opens new window:

```
private void OpenWindow(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var form = new SomeForm();
    form.MdiParent = this;
    form.Show();
}
```

And timer:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OpenWindow);
timer.Interval = 10000;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

And it throws error on setting `MdiParent`: `form.MdiParent = this;`

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'MainForm' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try using another Timer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317088/why-there-are-5-versions-of-timer-classes-in-net

Comment: its an idea! thank you, I'll try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing to a TextBox from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519233/writing-to-a-textbox-from-another-thread)

Comment: @user2190035 your idea helped me, if you write it as detailed answer, I'll accept it. P.S thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the other Timers because they handle the threading differently.

Explained here: [Why there are 5 Versions of Timer Classes in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317088/why-there-are-5-versions-of-timer-classes-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Threading Model](http://Threading%20Model) article, I think this should works in your cas:

```
var form = new SomeForm();
if (form.InvokeRequired)
{
    form.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
    form.MdiParent = this;
    }));
}
form.Show();
```

Or like this:

```
Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    form.MdiParent = this;
    form.Show();
}));
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but in this form I use xtraTabControl and I'm getting following error:  "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it."

Comment: @godot Have a look at my updated answer. it is another approach.

Comment: @godot Or you might need to add the `[STAThread]` attribute on your method.

Comment: thanks for answer again, +1 from me. Got another solution, just used another timer