# How do I write to a textbox from 3 threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have 3 threads that do different jobs and I need to collect the logs about them and write it to a text box. So I have:

```
public delegate void Notify(string message);
```

Each of the 3 classes of these threads has:

```
public event Data.Notify Notify;
```

(Data is just a static class where I keep general information for my app).
In the method Work() that is in all of these 3 classes I use:

```
Notify?.Invoke("message");
```

In the message I have information if the job is started, if it was successful or not. In the class of the Form I got:

```
Data.workingThread.Notify += Thread_Notify;
Data.readingThread.Notify += Thread_Notify;
Data.writingThread.Notify += Thread_Notify;
Data.writingThread.Start();
Data.workingThread.Start();
Data.readingThread.Start();
```

Where Thread_Notify is:

```
private void Thread_Notify(string message)
{
    tbLogs.Text += message;
}
```

When I run the code, It throws System.InvalidOperationException as I try to access 'tbLogs' not from a thread where it was created.
I tried async/await for this method and lock(tbLogs) but these didn't work for me

Comment: You could `BeginInvoke()` there to `tbLogs.AppendText(message)`. Or replace the events with a [IProgress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) delegate and `Report()` to the UI Thread. It's simpler to use Tasks instead of Threads in this case. How often will you add text to that control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, you can directly manage the text box only if you're in the main window thread.
Since you event (Thread_Notify) can be called from other threads, you can't use it directly because if it runs in a thread different from the main window one, it will throw an Exception.

For let it work, you have to write the notify in this way:

```
private void Thread_Notify(string message)
{
   Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
   {
      tbLogs.Text += message;
   }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

Comment: `Dispatcher` isn't typically used in WinForms.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you're using WinForms. In that case, have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519233/writing-to-a-textbox-from-another-thread

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Control.InvokeRequired` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired?view=netcore-3.1)
and the `Invoke` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netcore-3.1).

Use them to dispatch the textbox changes on the UI thread.

Example:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Action GetAction(string threadName) => () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var tid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                Thread_Notify($"{threadName} ({tid}): {i} ");
                int sleepMillis = 0;
                lock (rnd) sleepMillis = rnd.Next(0, 400);
                Thread.Sleep(sleepMillis);
            }
        };

        Task.WhenAll(
            Task.Run(GetAction("worker1")),
            Task.Run(GetAction("worker2")),
            Task.Run(GetAction("worker3"))
        ).ContinueWith(_ => Thread_Notify("Done."));
    }
    private void Thread_Notify(string message)
    {
        Action setText = delegate { tbLogs.Text += message + "\r\n"; };
        if (tbLogs.InvokeRequired)
        {
            tbLogs.Invoke(setText);
        }
        else
        {
            setText();
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to use the `System.Reactive.Linq` library to do the dispatching for you:

1. Create a subject.
2. Call `_subject.OnNext(message)` in worker threads.
3. Change the TextBox in a subscription.

Example:

```cs
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
// ...
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Subject<string> _messages = new Subject<string>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Action GetAction(string threadName) => () =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var tid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                _messages.OnNext($"{threadName} ({tid}): {i} ");
                int sleepMillis = 0;
                lock (rnd) sleepMillis = rnd.Next(0, 400);
                Thread.Sleep(sleepMillis);
            }
        };

        Task.WhenAll(
            Task.Run(GetAction("worker1")),
            Task.Run(GetAction("worker2")),
            Task.Run(GetAction("worker3"))
        ).ContinueWith(_ => _messages.OnNext("Done."));

        _messages
            .ObserveOn(this)
            .Subscribe(msg => tbLogs.AppendText(msg + "\r\n"));
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to check `InvokeRequired`: it's clearly required, since the event is raised by a worker thread. You risk a deadlock calling `Invoke()` here. Almost certain if the Control or its container is disposed or otherwise *blocked* in the meanwhile (unless `Thread.Join()` is called at some point, then it's `101%` certain). `BeginInvoke()` is safer here. Concurrency is the only *problem*.